# WordPress: .htaccess E8 redirect with permalinks. conditional redirect?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, internet-explorer-8

In WordPress, I set the page URL to be the post name via permalinks. The issue is I want to redirect ALL Internet Explorer 8 pages to a page called `ie/`. The issue is there are 2 `.htaccess` redirects. I have dug around and found a ton of Internet Explorer 8 redirects, but no conditional for my needs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/ie [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Yes, I have found that post, and added it to the start of my .htaccess file. But below that there is a wordpress rewrite that renames each page. I believe there is a conflict, because when in IE8 I get a redirect error "This webpage has a redirect loop."

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that you explained the situation, try this. The idea is that if the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is not `MSIE [6-8]` then it will go to the standard WordPress controller. But if `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is `MSIE [6-8]` then it goes to `http://website.com/ie`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/ie [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Or try swapping the order of those conditions like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/ie [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But I cannot guarantee this will work since it is idiosyncratic to a browser & server setup I do not have access to.

Also, I believe this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/ie [R=301,L]
```

Can be changed to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ie [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for this response! It's definitely what I was thinking in terms of a conditional rewrite statement. The only problem is I get a 500 error "Internal Server Error". I'm not sure what other information I can give you in order to help tweak the answer

Comment: I figured if the redirect happens before the server starts to read any files wordpress files, it would have a much faster load time, but I'm open to that option. I tried to add a php redirect as an wp action, without any success. Regardless you helped me understand htaccess much better, thank you!